# How to define the domain of a property in OWL?

Tags: rdf, ontology, owl, rdfs

I want to build an ontology to deal with persons infected or not infected by diseases:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
</rdf:RDF>
    <owl:Class rdf:about="&person;Disease"/>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&person;HealthyPerson">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&person;Person"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="&person;SickPerson"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&person;Person"/>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&person;SickPerson">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&person;Person"/>
    </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Graphically:

[image: class hierarchy as tree]

How can I define the property **has_disease(Person, Disease)** in such a way that an individual of type `Person` related to some `Disease` by `has_disease` will be inferred have type `SickPerson`, too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```xml
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="hasDisease">
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#SickPerson"/>
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Disease"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

Comment: I've test this but the reasoner seems to not be able to infered correctly. I used RacePro as a reasoner on Protege 4.

Comment: This forbids the use of `hasDisease` for anything that is not a person. A cat, a dog, a tree, can have diseases.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann you are absolutely right, but in the OP question only Person was mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an existential restriction for this. In the example below, the individual `joe` will be inferred to be a `SickPerson`

```xml
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="has_disease"/>
<owl:Class rdf:about="Disease"/>
<owl:Class rdf:about="Person"/>
<owl:Class rdf:about="SickPerson">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="has_disease"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="Disease"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Person"/>
</owl:Class>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="flu">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="Disease"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="joe">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="Person"/>
    <has_disease rdf:resource="flu"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```